# Unable to update state in React function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, setstate

I am new to React and unable to set state after fetching data from Firebase in `componentDidMount` function. I keep getting error

> contact is not defined inside the componentDidMount.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        contacts: [
            { name: 'sachin', number: '445343' },
            { name: 'nihil', number: '33335555' },
            { name: 'chicken', number: '434355' },

        ]
    }

    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
}


componentDidMount = () => {

    let currentComponent = this;
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            console.log(user.uid)
            var uid = user.uid;
            db.collection(uid)
                .get()
                .then((querySnapshot) => {
                    const contacts = []
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        const data = doc.data()
                        contacts.push(data)
                    })
                    console.log(contact)
                });

        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: You're calling `console.log(contact)`, but the variable is named `contacts` (with an `s` at the end).

Comment: You never call setState ? 

If you replace your console.log(contact) with this.setState({contacts});

Also, const contacts = querySnapshot.map(doc => doc.data()); would be a lot cleaner as well :)

Comment: oh sorry that my bad but still it doesn't work its just I used the const contact last time when I tried something differrent

Comment: @thsorens when i call this.setstate in place of console.log I get cannot read property setstate of undefined.

Comment: You probably have some scoping issues with your functions. you have already created currentComponent that binds to "this". Try using that then. currentComponent.setState(....

Usually, it shouldnt be necessary to bind anything to componentDidMount as you do in the constructor. Since it is a built in lifecycle function that you override, it should already have the correct "this" scope.